# Application level caching of XACML Authorization Details from WSO2 IDP

Tags: caching, wso2, authorization, xacml

We are working on application where we will create and store XACML policies in WSO2 server for authorization.

We are looking for the best way to authorise user whenever he is trying to access anything in application. Now we are not sure by this approach how much performance issue will come?

One way we can deal with this is when user is trying to login, at that time get his all details from IDP so we can cache it at application level and we don't have to make trip to wso2 idp each time user is performing any action. It may cause slow login but from there other application experience will be fast.

We just wanted to confirm that is this the correct approach? Is there any issue with this design or is there any better way we can use?

Answer (score 1):

I think its not the correct approach especially when we are talking about attribute based access control (ABAC) and when the attributes require to change frequently.

Also, when you are doing the policy evaluation its better to let PIP fetch the required attributes instead application sending all attributes and furthermore you may use the caching at WSO2 IS side also for XACML policy decision or attributes.

Apart from that for the better performance you may implement your PEP as thrift based. We did the same implementation and did a successful load testing for one of the most used application.

I would not recommend the caching at application side due the following reasons:

1. You have to make round trip for policy evaluation even if you cache attributes locally at application.
2. Caching attributes locally inside application will defeat the purpose in case the same policy to be used by other applications in future.
3. Allowing PIP to fetch required attributes at WSO2 side is recommended as it will ease the new application integration where you need not to worry fetching attributes for all new application integrations.
4. Caching can be done centrally at WSO2 IS server instead applying the cache at each application level.

P.S. - These are my personal views and opinions and it may not be perfect or best fit as per different requirements and business needs.

Comment: Hi Yusuf! Thank you very much for the answer!! I would like to know more about your implementation so we can take best out of opensource technologies. Can you please share your email or contact so we can talk.- thanks again for the answer.

Comment: Hi Buddh, I am reachable at ykhan.mca@gmail.com.

Comment: I found WSO2 IS caching for XACML quite annoying. If I enable caching with timeout of 60 seconds, it never invalidates the caching and XACML policy evaluation start behaving abnormally, like, rules that should actually evaluates to Permit, evaluates to Deny or somtimes logs just says that "ERROR {org.wso2.balana.finder.AttributeFinder} -  Failed to resolve any values for http://abcd.com/my-custom-id